# why does the slices read only the first and last line , skipping the line between them

Tags: python, django, find, slice

I can't correctly capture (read) the text received from the user
why is the data from the fill-in form not being read correctly? thank you in advance

I can 't understand the reason , where did I make a mistake ?

```
text = str(settings.tg_message)
          Name : { name }
          Phone : { phone }
          Vacancy : { vacancy }


    a = text.find("{")
    b = text.find("}")
    c = text.rfind("{")
    d = text.rfind("}")
    u = text.find("{")
    p = text.rfind("}")

    part_1 = text[0:a]
    part_2 = text[b + 1:c]
    part_3 = text[d + 1:u]
    part_4 = text[p:-2]

    text_message = part_1 + tg_name + part_2 + tg_phone + part_3 + tg_vacancy + part_4
```

desired result:

```
Name : john
Phone : +359557664848
Vacancy : courier
```

output:

```
Name : Jhon
Phone : { phone }
Vacancy : +359557664848courier
```

Comment: what is `text`? [ask] and [mre]

Comment: What even is `text`

Comment: Do you think that `u` and `p` contain other values than `a` and `d`?

Comment: perhaps I added little information due to inexperience .
I added the entire app entirely

Comment: @Claus Please provide us with a fixed value for `text`. We don't need all of this API calls. Create a minified example.

Comment: @Matthias Did I understand you correctly?

Comment: @Matthias my problem is that I manage to adjust the slices for 2 lines using variables a,b,c,d (I divide the text into 3 parts part_1,2,3)

but if I add 1 more line and variables u,p. the information is read incorrectly

Comment: `find`/`rfind` will always find the first/last index. So the item in between will never match, simply beacause the indexes are not the first and the last.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem is that you work with indexes, and thus search the first and last indexes for `{` and `}`. This thus means that no item in the middle can be used.

That being said, using such string manipulation will be *very* error prone: even if you manage to get this working, it is very sensitive to template changes: if for example you swap the order of the variables in the template, or omit one, it will start failing.

Moreover, you don't need this. Django already has a template render engine that you can use.

I would rewrite the `tg_message` setting to:

```
Name : {{ name }}
Phone : {{ phone }}
Vacancy : {{ vacancy }}
```

and then we can let Django do all the work:

```
from django.template import Context, Template

template = Template(settings.tg_message)

text_message = template.render(
    Context({'name': 'John', 'phone': '+359557664848', 'vacancy': 'courier'})
)
```

Comment: you're just a genius)!!!!!!!!!!!
thank you very much, the whole problem was solved in 2 minutes and thanks for the explanation, now I know more about find,rfind)